# Proof by contrapositive: P(x) has no positive roots

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, proof-writing

Prove (by contrapositive) that

> $P(x) = 3x^{72} + 5x^{59} + 6x^4 + 5x^2 + x + 10$

has no posivite roots.

I've interpreted a contrapositive statement of

> If $P(x)$ has any real roots, then $x < 0$

Have I misinterpreted what I need to prove? If not, how would I go about creating such a proof using a contrapositive like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $P(x_0)=0$ and $x_0 >0.$

We have that each  power $x_0^n$ is positive, thus $P(x_0) >10 $, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

By Descarte's rule as in the polynomial $f(x)=3x^{72}+5x^{59}+6x^4+5x^2+x+10=0$, there is no change of sign of coefficients. So this eqation will have at most 0 number of positive roots, so no positive root.

Moreover, for any positive value of $x=a$, $f(a)>0$ because all the terms(coefficients) are positive so the equality that $f(a)=0$ cannot hold when $a>0$.

Comment: I'm aware of this rule, but I don't see any feasible way of employing it in a proof by contrapositive. Any ideas?

Comment: @Trever Morris Moreover, for any positive value of $x=a$, $f(a)>0$ because all the terms(coefficients) are positive so the equality that $f(a)=0$ cannot hold when $a>0$. I have now addedd tis argument too.